# Jasny-Bootstrap using ".offcanvas-sm" in lessfile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, jasny-bootstrap

I would like to use `.offcanvas-sm` which is assigned to an `<nav>` element into the Less file. The Less file looks like:

```
@import "../../jasny-bootstrap.less";
.test {
  .offcanvas-sm;
}
```

Problem is that the Less processor says - class `offcanvas-sm` doesn't exist. Its from this "https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/master/less/offcanvas.less" Less file included in "jasny-bootstrap.less". But how can I import this code to a class?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is correct there, indeed `.offcanvas-sm` does not exist in the context you try to invoke it. The key word here is Scope: selectors defined in a media query can be used as a mixin only within this same media query block.

For this particular case [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) will do the trick. Scope handling of the `extend` is somewhat orthogonal to that of mixins, so selectors defined within media query blocks are open for "extending" from an outer scope (but not in opposite):

```
.test {
    &:extend(.offcanvas-sm all);
}
```

Or just:

```
.test:extend(.offcanvas-sm all) {

}
```

#### ---

[`all`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-) keyword is necessary in this case since `.offcanvas-sm` style is actually a set of two rulesets: `.offcanvas-sm` and `.offcanvas-sm.in`

Comment: Thx the first solution was excatliy what i needed :)